# The probabilities that the independent events

Tags: statistics

The probabilities that the independent events $A$, $B$, and $C$ will occur are: $\frac34$, $\frac12$, and $\frac14$.

What is the probability that at least one of the three events will happen?

My solution is

$1-$ Pr(intersection of the complements of $A$, $B$, $C$) thus $1-(\frac14\times\frac12\times\frac34)$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: What is the probability that none of the three events will happen? And what is the complement of that event?

Comment: you might want to respond to the questions asked in the comments above, else it is possible that your questions is closed..

Comment: I have already edited my question wwith my sollution. I hope this will help.

Comment: Your solution is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: That probability is the same with $p*=1-p(\mbox{ none of the events will happen})$